# Material Design support below Lollipop - crashes

Tags: android, android-theme, android-appcompat, material-design

I've been trying to implement the Material Design theme, following [these instructions](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html).

- I'm not using `ToolBar` (must I?)
- ALL my Activities extends ActionBarActivity.
- Using `getSupportActionBar()` all across the project.
- I'm compiling and targeting to API 21 in gradle (minimun is API 15).
- My `<application>` tag contains `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`
- Running the application on Lollipop device (with a specific v21 similar theme works).

My styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->

</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">
     <item name="displayOptions">useLogo|showHome</item>
    <item name="logo">@drawable/home_page_logo</item>
    <item name="background">@color/actionbar_background_color</item>
    <item name="textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTextStyle</item>
</style>
```

No matter what I tried, the application crashes the second I launch my main activity on `onCreate()` with this crash log:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:151)
 at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:138)
 at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:123)
```

Did anyone experience this issue? any suggestions on what might cause this?

**Edit:**
It's definitely something in my styles.xml theme. If I force the app to use the default Theme.AppCompat theme, it works.
What might cause a theme to fail? I verified the ActionBar attributes are not using "android:". Anything else?

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto yeah... verified again. All modules are targeting v21.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto clean, rebuild, gradle sync... basically everything

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**SOLVED...**

2 of my jar libs apparently have **generated** `values.xml` that contains styles of both `AppTheme` and `AppBaseTheme`.
I verified only our dependencies modules, as jar libraries shouldn't declare application themes, specially not with the name of  the default ones.

Before posting the answer, I added to my `AndroidManifest.xml` `<application>` 
`tools:replace="android:theme"` and declared the new theme, assuming it'll work and my application will override any other theme.

The **solution** eventually, stupid as it is, was to rename my own `AppTheme` and `AppBaseTheme` to different names and now it works.
Hours spent on such a trivial fix. Hopefully, this will spare some time for others.

Answer (score 2):

`parent` should be `Theme.AppCompat` not `@style/Theme.AppCompat`.

Using `@style/` you'll be using the style from the Android API 21, and it must be the style from the `AppCompat` library.

**edit:**

probably same thing for the `Widget.AppCompat`

**edit2:**

like this

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->

</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">
     <item name="displayOptions">useLogo|showHome</item>
    <item name="logo">@drawable/home_page_logo</item>
    <item name="background">@color/actionbar_background_color</item>
    <item name="textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTextStyle</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried that as well, for all parents.

Comment: that's super weird. Getting to work tomorrow I'll check how's on our app

Comment: very weird... I'm starting to think it's related to a bad jar library that generates a values.xml with a Holo theme.

Comment: did you try using `Theme.Material.AppCompat` (I'm writing just by what I remember, it might be slightly different, but I remember that such a thing exists.)

Answer (score 1):

Try remove the "@style/" from the first line in the styles.xml so you have:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, my themes.xml had the following:

```
style name="Theme.DollarBucket" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar" />
```

for some weird reason there was an "android:" tag, removing that solved my issue.