# How to use android:Theme.Material (Material theme) in styles.xml android?

Tags: android, material-design, android-appcompat, android-theme, android-styles

In my application, I am trying to implement `android:Theme.Material` as a parent  theme in styles `values-21` folder:

```
 <!-- res/values-21/styles.xml -->
 <resources>
 <!-- your theme inherits from the material theme -->
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <!-- theme customizations -->
      <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/text_primary</item>
    <!-- darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <!-- theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/primary_dark</item>
   </style>
 </resources>
```

After running the app, I am getting below `error`

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

In values folder. I have below style

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

But, if I add the same `Theme.AppCompat.Light` in `values-21 folder` its working fine. but `actionbar color` is not changing.

**Why can't i use the material design theme in `values-21 folder`?
How to solve this problem?**

(note: my application `minsdk verison` is `13` and `maxsdk version` is `22`)

> My activity extends AppCompactActivity

Comment: You can use appcompat for this

Comment: @SandeepSingh i am using appcompat as well. which appcampat i need to use?

Comment: you should use ApcompatActivity instead of ActionBarActivity or Activity if you are using 22.1.1 build version

Comment: @Chandru i am using AppcompatActivity only

Comment: what is your issue exactly?? ActionBar color isnt it right??

Comment: @Chandru : Not exactly . ActionBar color is second problem.my first problem is why i can't use the "android:Theme.Material" in values-21 folder, i mean in theme. if i use material theme its getting force close

Comment: @John Valid question. I dont know why. But I am using Theme.AppCompat.Light for material designs in my project in syles for both values-21 and values.xml folder. It is working well and good.

Comment: @Chandru . thanks for the response. the same thing what you are using that is working for me as well. if you find a solution for this please share it. if i found i do the same .

Comment: @John please edit and align your question.

Comment: @Chandru . sorry to say this. my english is not good, i did my best, do you think i need to change the tittle of question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80131/discussion-between-chandru-and-john).

Comment: This is one possible, albeit very precise, solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28570785/material-design-support-below-lollipop-crashes?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your are using an `AppCompatActivity`, just use only a style in your `res/values/styles.xml`, and check the namespace that your are using for colorPrimary, colorPrimaryDark....

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
 </style>
```

Comment: how do we change the actionbar text color in this?

Comment: <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/text_primary</item> this is used to change the Text color of action bar .

Comment: Above answer is working fine. but still i don't know why can't we use the material theme. thanks for the answer @GabrieleMariotti

Comment: @Gabriele Mariotti if we use AppCompat themes(Which has platform independent theme family), do we still need to create different values folders for android platform versions? I don't think it is required, if we use Appcompat themes.

Comment: How do we use both AppCompat theme and Material theme for different Api targets? Or isn't it possible wehen using AppCompatActivity?

Comment: What about if you do not want an AppCompatActivity and want to use straight activities instead?

Answer (score 7):

[image]

Your app theme is defined in the manifest file:

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

You will find this style defined in `/res/values/styles.xml`.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Using `AppCompat` allows your themes to be used even for devices older than Android 5.0. The main Material Design Themes are shown below.

## Dark Theme

[image]

## Light Theme

[image]

## Light Theme with Dark Action Bar

[image]

## Further Reading

- [Using the Material Theme](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html) (Android docs)

Comment: So why no example with the Material theme? I guess you avoided a direct answer because it is not as simple as this.

Comment: @AndrewS， my examples all use the `AppCompat` themes. These themes are actually Material themes, but they have the additional advantage of supporting earlier Android versions. I use `AppCompat` whenever possible in order to support the largest number of devices. Using `Theme.Material` lacks that advantage.

Comment: Ah ok. I was expecting to see material.light  or something in the theme. I was assuming these were the old themes from the pre-material era.

Comment: @Suragch can you tell me how can i get white action bar and status bar with black icons and text i can't find a proper theme i know this can be achieved pragmatically

Comment: @MateenChaudhry, Use a `Theme.AppCompat.Light` theme and change the `colorPrimary` and `colorPrimaryDark` to white in the *colors.xml* file.